# readable is not async iterable in Node Google Cloud Storage download method

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, create-react-app

I am trying to read data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket from a React application.
My bucket cannot be public to the internet. I have created a service account to give my app the authorization to access the bucket.
I can access the bucket and list the files but cannot download the content of the file: I get the following error:
**TypeError: readable is not async iterable**

I created my app with create-react-app and my node module versions are:
`"react": "^18.2.0",`
`"@google-cloud/storage": "^6.8.0",`

My code is as follows:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Storage} from "@google-cloud/storage";
import jsonKey from '../keys/`[my-json-key].json';


export default function TestsLight() {

    const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(null);

    /*  Files and Bucket details: */
    const file_name = 'my-file.csv';
    const bucketName = 'my-bucket.appspot.com';

    /*  Storage instantiation: works:   */
    const storage = new Storage({credentials: jsonKey});
    const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
    const myFile = bucket.file(file_name);

    /*  file download: DOES NOT WORK: returns `TypeError: readable is not async iterable`   */
    myFile.download(function (err, contents) {
        console.log('err: ', err);
        console.log('contents: ', contents);
        contents && setFileData(contents);
    });

    return (
        fileData ?
            <div>
                {fileData}
            </div> :
            <div>
                <span>no data</span>
            </div>
    )
}
```

I followed the steps from

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/latest

I tried to:

- create a bucket: *works*
- list the files in a bucket: *works*
- download the content of the file in memory or in a local file: *does not work*: **TypeError: readable is not async iterable**

Any idea of what is wrong?
Many thanks

*Edited 13/01/2023: added tag `node.js`*

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with the Google team in charge of the storage client libraries and the reason it does not work is because my code runs in the browser and the storage library is only meant to run on the server side.
See [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/2128) for full discussion and details.